# Api Pagination Call to undefined method stdClass::links() on laravel 8

Tags: laravel, rest, pagination, paginator, laravel-pagination

hello can you help me? so i am paginating on server side, but when i try to display on client side i get error like this...

i can say I can't use firstItem(), Thanks for your response, I hope this gets the answer..

In Controller

```
$response = Http::withHeaders([
            'X-Authorization'  =>  'NkKeAs7Og8O6WcNste9OsAjkui2pSZnjZr6WOcDf1EjU1UDPuz88CATNqFI2rkSN'
        ])->get('http://www.Api.net/api/get-produk', [
            'type_product'  => $filter,
            'limit'      => $request->length,
            'offset'      =>  $request->start,
        ]);
        $data = json_decode($response);
```

In Rest API

```
$produk = Daftarproduk::select('cat_number', 'brand', 'nama_produk', 'host', 'reactivity', 'clone_type', 'application', 'pack_size', 'type_product', 'pack_category', 'price')
            ->where('type_product', $request->get('type_product'))
            ->offset($request->offset)
            ->limit($request->limit)
            ->paginate();
```

In View

```
<tbody>
                @foreach ($produk->data as $item)
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{ $loop->iteration }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->cat_number }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->brand }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->nama_produk }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->host }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->reactivity }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->clone_type }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->application }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->pack_size }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->type_product }}</td>
                        <td>{{ $item->price }}</td>
                    </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-start">
            Showing
            {{ $produk->firstItem() }}
            to
            {{ $produk->lastItem() }}
            of
            {{ $produk->total() }}
            Entries
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex justify-content-end">
            {{ $produk->links() }}
        </div>
```

Comment: Check this : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination good luck

Comment: ->paginate(10); // 10 any other numbers